# How to simplify this angular duplicated code in promise?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a new Angular developer. I wonder if there is an elegant way to simplify the duplicated code below.

```
addTransaccion() {
    try {
      if (this.idTransaccion === '0') {
        this.transaccionesSrv.addTransaccion(data)
          .then(res => {
            if (res) {
              this.router.navigate(['/cuentas/transacciones'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
            }
          });
      } else {
        this.transaccionesSrv.actualizarTransaccion(data, this.idTransaccion)
          .then(res => {
            if (res) {
              this.router.navigate(['/cuentas/transacciones'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
            }
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.envioFormularioOk = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
 (this.idTransaccion === '0' ? this.transaccionesSrv.addTransaccion(data) : 
this.transaccionesSrv.actualizarTransaccion(data, this.idTransaccion))
          .then(res => {
            if (res) {
              this.router.navigate(['/cuentas/transacciones'], { queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
            }
          });
```

but I think it's harder to read

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const manageTransaction = (data)=>{
 if (this.idTransaccion === '0')
    return transaccionesSrv.addTransaccion(data);
  else
    return this.transaccionesSrv.actualizarTransaccion(data,
                                                       this.idTransaccion);
};
const navigate = (res) => {
 if (res) {
    this.router.navigate(['/cuentas/transacciones'], { 
       queryParamsHandling: "preserve" });
   }
};


const addTransaccion = () => {
  manageTransaccion(data)
  .then(res => navigate(res););
  .catch((error)=> {
    this.envioFormularioOk = false;
  });}
```